# I can not post content to php through ajax with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have a problem when sending post content to a php file via ajax. My intention is to send an object that contains the data that will be used in the file save.php and it has to process the response so that it appears in an alert window.

```
var iden = true;

var object = {

    'titulo': 'In the mountain',
    'dest': 'Single of',
    'edit': true,
    'previ': 'yes',
    'iden': iden
};

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', "save.php", false);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.send( object);

if (xhr.status == 200) {
    xhr.onload = function () {
        alert(this.responseText);
    };
} else {
    alert('error');
}
```

The problem is that when trying to send the data I get this message in console:

> Test.js: 56 [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main
>   thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end
>   user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Line 56 corresponds to:

`Xhr.open ('POST', 'save.php', false);`

If I set the async parameter to **true**, it jumps the else from the conditional if **(xhr.status == 200)** and displays the error alert.

Where could the problem be?

Also say that with jquery it works perfectly, but I would like to do it with Javascript.

**With jquery:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "save.php",
    type: "post",   
    data: object
}).done(function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

**EDIT:**

**console.log(xhr);**

> XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 1, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false,
>   upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: function…} onabort :
>   null onerror : null onload : null onloadend : null onloadstart : null
>   onprogress : null onreadystatechange : function () ontimeout : null
>   readyState : 4 response : "" responseText : "" responseType : ""
>   responseURL : "http://localhost/save.php" responseXML : null status :
>   200 statusText : "OK" timeout : 0

Comment: Well, I can say use jQuery then :).

Comment: But I would like to be able to do it with javascript and not use the jquery library just for this. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this line of code: `xhttp.open("POST", "save.php", false);` and set the third parameter to `true`. And follow this example if it can work.

```js
var object = {
    'titulo': 'In the mountain',
    'dest': 'Single of',
    'edit': true,
    'previ': 'yes',
    'iden': iden
};

function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "save.php", true);
  xhttp.send(object);
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<h2>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h2>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Good, only an annotation, that xhttp.open, by default has its third parameter true as default, then not is necessary write the third parameter. [More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#open())

Comment: @PabloCesarCordovaMorales thanks for clarifying, and as the articles says it will be true as default you dont need to add it

Comment: I just changed everything and it gives the same errors. It does not even send the data per post to the php file.

I have edited the first post with additional information from the console.